# how to find domain of marginal pdf when its two variables domain are dependent

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, density-function, mathematica

I have a pdf $f(x,y)=1/π, 0< x^2+ y^2 <1$； 0, e.w.

Here, we can see $-\sqrt{1-x^2} < y < \sqrt{1-x^2}$

So, the marginal pdf of $X$ is $$\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2} 1/πy \, dy\,.$$

and finally, I have $f(x)= 2/π \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

I do not know how to define the range of $f(x)$, can I present it in $y$ form
like ：

$-\sqrt{1-y^2} < x < \sqrt{1-y^2}$?

Looks not solving anything. Can any one tell me how to find the domain of $f(x)$?

Comment: Your pdf isn't a pdf -- it doesn't integrate to 1.

Comment: @Glen_b    I add " 0, e.w" in the question. Is this a pdf now? or you mean my result of the marginal pdf of X is wrong?  p.s. thanks for your edit. I'll learn how to show the mathematical formula next time.

Comment: There was a typo earlier where it is writtent ahat $f(x,y)=1/2$ rather than $1/\pi$.

Comment: @S.F.Yeh for getting your mathematics done See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal distribution is $$\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2} \frac1\pi\, dy=\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi}.$$

We do not multiply $y$ in the integral.

The support would be from $-1$ to $1$. These are the $x$ values that the unit disk can take.

Comment: This looks correct (so upvoted) but for what looks rather like routine bookwork/assignment type questions we usually give hints and guidance rather than explicit solutions. See the [help/on-topic] under *Homework*

Comment: I did not relate it to the unit disk. thanks for your hint